# How to replace a value from one list with a value from a other one randomly?

Tags: python, list

I'm been trying to do this, but with no results, the following is my code. So I have a list of 100 number, split into two halves, now based on a user choice I have to mutate a value of one list with a value from the other,

```
pop_size = []
c1 = 0
c2 = 0
u1 = 0.5
seed(1)
for i in range(0,100):
  x= randint(1,10)
  pop_size.append(x)
s1 = np.array(pop_size[:50])
s2 = np.array(pop_size[50:])



choice_var = input('Choose a species no 0 or 1')
if choice_var == 0 :
  indx1 = randint(0, len(s1)-1)
  s1[indx1] = choice(s2)
```

But no results are coming, I would appreciate any help

Comment: use `int(input('Choose a species no 0 or 1'))`

Comment: Hi Newb. Welcome to the StackOverflow. Your question is so much confusing. Can you please make some edits to your code, and if you cannot explain it through code, then provide Algorithm. So that more contributors can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I have tested it and it is running.

```
import numpy as np
import random

pop_size = []
c1 = 0
c2 = 0
u1 = 0.5
random.seed(1)
for i in range(0,100):
  x= random.randint(1,10)
  pop_size.append(x)
s1 = np.array(pop_size[:50])
print(s1)
s2 = np.array(pop_size[50:])
#print(s2)



choice_var = int(input('Choose a species no 0 or 1'))
#choice_var = int(0)
if choice_var == 0 :
  indx1 = random.randint(0, len(s1)-1)
  print(indx1)
  print(random.choice(s2))
  s1[indx1] = random.choice(s2)

print(s1)
```